# Image slider inside fragment child using ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have tried image slider and solved error of .this file using getActivity().But as soon as i open the app it will stop how to solve that.

java code that extends fragment

## .java code

```
public class CargoHome extends Fragment {
View myView;
Animation fade_in, fade_out;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cargo_home, container, false);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.backvf);

    fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
    fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out);

    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(fade_in);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(fade_out);
    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();


    return myView;

}
```

}

xml code

### .xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/backvf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bolt" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/nano" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/zest" />



    </ViewFlipper>
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fade_in and fade_out xml file

#### fade_in and fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" />


</set>
```

Comment: use getActivity() instead of this

Comment: Please post your code **as text, not as images**!

Comment: Simply replace `this` by `getActivity()`. Error solved!

Comment: please add more details, tell what you have tried, else you will be blocked from stack overflow from asking question.

Comment: sorry everyone i am new to this so i dont know how to post a code now i corrected it and I am working on Android app for Cars where I want to show image slider in my home page.but as soon as i run my app it will stop and come out to launcher what is the error in code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using it on fragment replace this line

```
 fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

with this:

```
 fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

OR With

```
 fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getAppicationContext, android.R.anim.fade_in);
    fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getAppicationContext, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getActivity()` by `myView` in this line

```
viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) myView.findViewById(R.id.backvf);
```